# Jquery Accordion - Make Clicked element scroll to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, accordion

I am using this accordion script for an FAQ page: http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/accordion.html

It's great except for one problem which is especially evident on mobile devices. When you click on a question and it has a lot of content inside, it expands upwards off the screen, to where you have to scroll up to see the question and the beginning of the content.

Ideally I'd like to have it to where the script scrolls the question to the top of the page/viewport when you click on it. If anyone has an idea of what to tweak in the script that would be amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this. You don't need a plugin for an accordion:

**Edited version with icons, default open, and touch enabled scroll to top**

https://jsfiddle.net/07fdq3t1/10/

Add the class show to the one you want to open.

This could probably be written more efficiently as there's repeating code, but it should work.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordion').click(function(){
        if($(this).next('.container').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).removeClass('show');
            $(this).next('.container').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $('.accordion').find('.container:visible').slideUp();
            $('.accordion').removeClass('show');
            $(this).addClass('show');
            $(this).next('.container').slideDown();
        }         
    });
    $('.accordion').on( "touchstart", function(){
        if($(this).next('.container').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).removeClass('show');
            $(this).next('.container').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $('.accordion').find('.container:visible').slideUp();
            $('.accordion').removeClass('show');
            $(this).addClass('show');
            $(this).next('.container').slideDown();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 200);
        } 
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Sample Content</div>
            <p>Content here....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Sample Content</div>
            <p>Content here....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="accordion show">Heading<span></span></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Sample Content</div>
            <p>Content here....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="accordion">Heading<span></span></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div>Sample Content</div>
            <p>Content here....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note you will need to include jQuery in your code.

Comment: Sorry I just edited the jsfiddle, in case someone clicked on the old link in the post. I didn't realize my code didn't update. As noted, https://jsfiddle.net/07fdq3t1/1/ should work.

Comment: Wow thanks a ton. That looks awesome, only problem is I'm using some of the extra features in that plugin, such as the DefaultOpen feature, so I'd probably have to stick with the plugin unless you know a way to implement a way where I can specify a specific element to be open on page load?

Comment: also I do utilize the expand/collapse icons in the plugin css. I do need those icons too.

Comment: Just edited my answer. You may check the new version. https://jsfiddle.net/07fdq3t1/3/

Comment: Sorry there's a bug that was introduced in the process. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Should be fixed now. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: Wow, this is incredible, can't believe you went through all this effort. Thank you SO much! This isn't a big deal but do you know of a reliable way to only have the "scroll to top" feature active on mobile only? If not no worries, thanks again.

Comment: Just updated the code. The new code should work for touch action scrolling.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. If you have just a little more time, there's one thing that's still missing from the original script. It used to open the content slowly/animated. Right now it opens immediately without any animation. Is there any way to get that back in? Either way thank you for all this awesome work.